# Limit of concurrent PHP scripts

Tags: php, apache

I have some PHP scripts that process data
unfortunately I can only run 6 script simultaneously
it seems that there is some sort of limitation in php or apache that makes the 7th script waits until another script ends

the script only processes data, there isn't any kind of connection with the database or any web request

How can I increase this limit?

Comment: set_time_limit(0);    or set execution time =0 in your php.ini  file

Comment: that could caused by a combination of apache and apache module settings. You may try your question at **[SuperUser](http://superuser.com)** , among other things. Also, if you are using PhpStorm/XDebug , you should not for long haul processes like this, they will slow down your workers significantly. If you need it, make certain that the connection limit of Xdebug is set to a high number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Leo - How are you running these scripts simultaneously? Is it web browser calling it (as you have mentioned apache in question)? -- browser has simultaneously connection limit. *OR* some other scenario.

Comment: I run in the browser several different scripts that take nearly an hour to finish, however the seventh script only begins to run when any other stop running

Comment: see http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top -- "Connections per Hostname"...may be you are hitting this limit of 6 in Chrome or FF ?

Comment: You're right, the problem was the browser, I was using Chrome now I'm using Firefox and I changed this limitation, eveything is working fine now.

Comment: @Leo how did you change that limitation?

Comment: I changed `network.http.max-connections-per-server` and `network.http.max-connections` in about:config of Firefox

Answer (score 1):

**place this function top of each page.**

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

> *more details you can found on* 
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: can you provide us code, may be it's going in infinite loop.

Comment: I just want to run more than 6 scripts simultaneously